Compositor Vector Blur is messy and inaccurate (EEVEE)
Not sure what info I can put. My setup is identical to the resources I've found, except mine doesn't work. My version is 4.2.1 LTS, and I'm using eevee. The blur looked significantly less choppy until I added some extra camera movement. The objects are just two small emissive icospheres; the prior movement these objects make looks fine, but it seems this choppiness and artifacting begins to occur at a higher speed(?). The objects are not obscured by anything, and there are no volumetrics or anything that should be physically interfering with them aside from their own movement. They do not rotate at all.
The objective is to give these two objects motion blur, without giving that effect to anything else. Raytracing is enabled, Motion blur is disabled, render is 64 samples...
Here's what it looks like:

Here's roughly what it should look like (edited):

Other view layers taken out for simplicity.

Looks like a bug? Bugs are off-topic. Can you share your blend file https://blend-exchange.com
